# Twitter Bootstrap: Modifying pixel width thresholds for col-sm

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following issue (best illustrated by images):

Medium width (**using col-md-3**)
[image]

Small width (**using col-sm-6**)
[image]

Width between small and medium
[image]

The columns resize at **979px-1199px** width to show the last image (the bad configuration)...

**The other option for me would be creating an intermediary class .. say col-mdsm or something and setting that pixel range for it?**

Comment: So, regarding the 'bad configuration', what exactly do you want it to be (in other words, what is that you are trying to achieve?) - why not use `col-sm-3` AND `col-md-6` (or `col-xs-3` for that matter)

Comment: Well I want three columns at medium width, not 2.. that is the issue.

Comment: Plus with col-sm-3 you would get more columns at a smaller width.. not what I'm looking for.

Comment: do you always want 3 columns (regardless of screen size)? if so, use `col-xs-4` (the bootstrap grid is 12-columns width, so 12/4 = 3).  If you specify the `xs` column width, it will scale up to the bigger screens (always showing 3 columns)

Comment: You can also use more than one class: `class="col-xs-4 col-lg-2"` and the grid will adjust accordingly.

Comment: No, I do not want 3 columns at all widths.. I want 2 at the small and between sm and md and 3 at md

Comment: Then see the suggestion by @hungerstar, use multiple classes depending on the the layout you want for the screen size (though, I would change it to `class='col-xs-6 col-md-4'`)

Comment: Sorry that is what I have.. I had a typo in my question.. This problem exists with those class names.. I have col-sm-6 and col-md-4

Comment: A little markup might help.

Comment: Sorry I have bolded the classes now in my question

Comment: Anyway, my question is not how do I fix this.. But how do I create an intermediary class using TB or modify the existing width range for col-sm class

Comment: I am not sure, I follow.  The reason your 'bad configuration' exists is because the inner content (the wording) is too long to fit at the given width so it wraps (and creates a new line) and changes the height of the element.  It does not necessarily mean that the config is bad. It's just the content does not fit in the given space to 'align' properly

Comment: And of course, to create an intermediary class, you can use @leiter0499's answer (change `.element-class-name` to your suggested class name: `.col-mdsm-x`)

Comment: The column sizing changes at 1199 and this causes the text to wrap.. Do you see what I'm saying ?

Comment: Sorry, the parent column sizing changes at 1199.. Forcing these child columns to shrink, and forcing the text to wrap.

Comment: At 1199, the text is too big to fit so it wraps (seems normal behaviour). How do you expect it to behave? - I must be missing something here

Comment: The columns don't change fluidly, they change at specified intervals.. 1199 is the interval where the column width changes down.. thus forcing the text to wrap.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68001/discussion-between-ochi-and-abram).

Comment: So you want to prevent the "stair-stepping" behavior as the browser width decreases?

Comment: No I don't want to prevent that. I want to create an extra step in between md and sm with the pixed range of 979px-1199px

Answer (score 1):

You can change the font size for this element manually:

```
@media (min-width: 979px and max-width: 1199px) {
    .elem-class-name {
        font-size: 13px; /*Needs to be adjusted */
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good idea, and one I've considered, but I'm wondering about the possibility of creating an intermediary class or modifying the limits of col-sm?

Comment: @Abram Of course you can freely change the dimensions of bootstrap, e.g. the Padding/Margin/width etc. And you can also create your own classes. You only should implement your modifications to the code after you implemented the "normal" bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to your specific question, but I hope it will help others to "Step Away from the Grid System" when it hinders the desired result.

If you look at GetBootstrap.com -- the official Bootstrap website -- in the Glyphicon example that is a list and it's not a class that comes with Bootstrap. It's not the grid system. In fact there's a lot of custom CSS on GetBootstrap.com with added classes. If you look at any of the showcase sites, there's plenty of custom CSS and plenty of not using anything to do with Bootstrap. You can hardly find a Bootstrap class in Vogue.com yet it's still part of the showcase sites, go figure.

*Anyway, I would roll a custom list, just like GetBootstrap.com did for their Glyphicon list:*

## DEMO: https://jsbin.com/yumoca/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
   <ul class="audio-list list-inline">
      <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer.</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer.</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer.</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer.</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer.</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.audio-list {
    text-align: center;
}

.audio-list li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
    white-space:normal;
}

.audio-list li a {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #f7f7f7;
    text-align:center;
    color:inherit;
}

@media (min-width:768px) { 
    .audio-list {
        font-size: 0px;
        text-align:left;
    }
    .audio-list li {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 50%;
        font-size: 14px;
        vertical-align: top;
    }  
  
}

@media (min-width:992px) { 
    .audio-list li {
        width: 33.33%
    }
}
```